# Node library for accessing memcached / redis / internal storage

Tags: node.js, redis, memcached, npm

Does anybody know a library abstracting the access to memcached or redis *and* providing and internal storage (so it's possible to develop without a local memcached / redis instance)?

I know the access libraries for [memcached](https://www.npmjs.org/package/memcached) and [redis](https://www.npmjs.org/package/redis) but I am not aware of an abstraction library on top of them.

All I basically need is a simple key-value store. I am aware of [ueberDB](https://github.com/Pita/ueberDB) but that library does not offer an internal storage (though you could add support for it).

-- ooxi

Comment: how can you develop with redis/memcached without depending on local installation?? are you referring to data structures?

Comment: The application I'm developing is a simple cache. In production it will use a memcached instance to centrally store data from different processes but while developing it would be great not to depend on a local memcached instance

Comment: Sounds like a bad practice. You may discover problem in production because you don't use the same backend than during development. Redis is easy to install, why don't use set up one in your development environment?

Comment: You are right, both memcached and redis are easy to install. But if the configuration of the services is different from the one in production there is not much gain compared to a different backend. Issues with services are caught in staging, no direct commits from dev to production are allowed in our setup

Comment: you should reconsider the development cycle, establish development modes and testing production mode locally..of course i assume you use some kind of VCS where everyone has their own branch where commits code.

Other than that configuration of services are not something that should not allow you to install services. There can be no application development without required development services. UNLESS you write tests mocking objects/methods and the entire module which interacts with the service..